# Circular view path

Tags: servlets, spring-mvc, http-post

I am using Spring MVC 3 and all I am trying to do is submitting a form with post request and redirecting the post request handler on the controller to some page. But I am getting the following error when I try to do that:

```
javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [thanks.htm]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/wickedlysmart/thanks.htm] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

Following is the code I am using:

Request handler:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="thanks")
public ModelAndView thanks() {
    logger.debug("redirecting..");
    return new ModelAndView("thanks");
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="talk")
public String processContactForm(HttpServletRequest req) {      
    //...
    return "redirect:thanks";
}
```

View resolver in spring application context:

```
<bean class="org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver">

    <property name="prefix" value="" />
    <property name="suffix" value=".htm" />

</bean>
```

I am not quite able to understand what is going on here. I see "redirecting.." being logged and then I get this error. Could someone help me with this issue?

Thanks.

Comment: I changed the redirect from "thanks" to "captured" and modified the "value" for the redirect request handler from "thanks" to "captured" as well and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @dragon66: Like you suggested, I just added an answer and accepted it as well. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following solved the problem:

```
@RequestMapping(method=RequestMethod.GET, value="captured")
public ModelAndView thanks() {
    logger.debug("redirecting..");
    return new ModelAndView("thanks");
}
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.POST, value="talk")
public String processContactForm(HttpServletRequest req) {      
    //...
    return "redirect:captured";
}
```

As you could see, I just changed the redirect from "thanks" to "captured" and modified the "value" for the redirect request handler from "thanks" to "captured" as well and it worked. Thanks.