# How to reflect the incoming GET request in text?

Tags: java, spring, rest, spring-mvc, spring-boot

I'm using Spring MVC and Springboot (assume latest version) to put up a simple web service that returns some text.

I was able to figure out how to use **@RequestMapping** and **@PathVariable** annotations to show one of the URL path variables as a response from the server (e.g. if the user goes to .../my_user_id/ in the browser, they can then see some text in the browser that includes that user_id... since the service returned it as a response).

*I need help with figuring out how to* capture the GET HTTP request the user's browser makes and then display it in text form as a response in the browser (I want to display the headers and the request body as plain text).

I've done some research, but none of the solutions available work properly. Is anyone aware of the right approach / feasibility here?

An approach I tried:

- http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/

Some threads on the error I get back when I tried the above approach:

- [Spring RestTemplate - how to enable full debugging/logging of requests/responses?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7952154/spring-resttemplate-how-to-enable-full-debugging-logging-of-requests-responses)
- http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/roo/84244-circular-view-path-resourcenotfound
- [Circular view path](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10567341/circular-view-path)
- [How to avoid the "Circular view path" exception with Spring MVC test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813615/how-to-avoid-the-circular-view-path-exception-with-spring-mvc-test)
- http://myshittycode.com/2014/01/17/mockmvc-circular-view-path-view-would-dispatch-back-to-the-current-handler-url-view-again/

More on Spring MVC, which I'm heavily using:

- http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html

Anyhow. When using the below @Controller, I get an error:

```
@RestController
public class HelloController {

@RequestMapping("/")
public String index() {
    return "Welcome to your home directory";
}

@RequestMapping(value="/mydata/{userId}", method=RequestMethod.GET)
public String printTheUser(@PathVariable String userId) {
    return "The data for " + userId + " would live here";
}


@RequestMapping("/summary_data/")
public String index3() {
    return "All summary data would appear here";
}

private String server = "localhost";
private int port = 8080;

@RequestMapping("/request_mirror/**")
public @ResponseBody String mirrorRest(@RequestBody String body, HttpMethod method, HttpServletRequest request,
    HttpServletResponse response) throws URISyntaxException {
    URI uri = new URI("http", null, server, port, request.getRequestURI(), request.getQueryString(), null);

    RestTemplate restTemplate = new RestTemplate();

    ResponseEntity<String> responseEntity =
        restTemplate.exchange(uri, method, new HttpEntity<String>(body), String.class);

    return responseEntity.getBody();
    }
}
```

When running this code and navigating to localhost:8080/request_mirror/stuff3/, I get the following error:

```
Whitelabel Error Page.   This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Mon Feb 08 15:41:13 EST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).
Required request body content is missing:    org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@a35a9b3f
```

Now, when I try a different approach (another @Controller) - the code looks like:

```
@Controller
@RequestMapping("/site")
public class SecondController{

@Autowired
private HttpServletRequest request;

@RequestMapping(value = "/{input:.+}", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public ModelAndView getDomain(@PathVariable("input") String input) {

    ModelAndView modelandView = new ModelAndView("result");

    modelandView.addObject("user-agent", getUserAgent());
    modelandView.addObject("headers", getHeadersInfo());

    return modelandView;

}

//get user agent
private String getUserAgent() {
    return request.getHeader("user-agent");
}

//get request headers
private Map<String, String> getHeadersInfo() {

    Map<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();

    Enumeration headerNames = request.getHeaderNames();
    while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
        String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
        String value = request.getHeader(key);
        map.put(key, value);
    }

    return map;
}
}
```

For the above code (SecondController), (sourced from http://www.mkyong.com/java/how-to-get-http-request-header-in-java/),  I get the following error, when I try to navigate to localhost:8080/site/stuff123456789... (but I can see the header keys and values from the request in the Map upon inspection... just not sure how to display them as text in the browser as the response).

```
This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.

 Mon Feb 08 16:10:47 EST 2016
There was an unexpected error (type=Internal Server Error, status=500).
Circular view path [stuff123456789]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/site/stuff123456789] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
```

Comment: An example of what you've tried and what you're trying to achieve would be helpful.

Comment: Thanks @tanenbring I'll add the code I've tried thus far and the issues with it...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

EDIT: Use the HttpEntity to get the body in case it's empty.

I'm not sure exactly what you're trying to achieve, but think this might be close:

```
@RequestMapping(value="/echoRequest")
public @ResponseBody String echoRequest(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity, HttpServletRequest req) {
    String out = "";
    List<String> names = req.getHeaderNames();
    for (String name : names) {
        out += (name + ": " + req.getHeader(name) + "\n");
    }
    if (httpEntity.hasBody()) {
        out += httpEntity.getBody();
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: Thanks @tanenbring! I tried adding your solution method to my SecondController.java (see code in my updated problem description), and went to "http://localhost:8080/site/echoRequest/". 
..............
The error I get then is ------Whitelabel Error Page --------This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.-------Mon Feb 08 17:38:38 EST 2016-----There was an unexpected error (type=Bad Request, status=400).-------Required request body content is missing: org.springframework.web.method.HandlerMethod$HandlerMethodParameter@5c3f7f09'

Comment: Thanks @tanenbring! That worked well. I modified your code just a bit and added the method mapping to "/echoRequest" into my SecondController.java. Then, navigating to localhost:8080/site/echoRequest/ returned me the browser's request headers (and body, which was empty due to the nature of my request).

Comment: `@RequestMapping(value="/echoRequest")
 public @ResponseBody String echoRequest(HttpEntity<String> httpEntity, HttpServletRequest req) {
     String out = "";

  Enumeration<String> headerNames = req.getHeaderNames();
  while (headerNames.hasMoreElements()) {
   String key = (String) headerNames.nextElement();
   String value = req.getHeader(key);
   out += (key + ": " + req.getHeader(key) + "\n");
  }
  
     if (httpEntity.hasBody()) {
         out += httpEntity.getBody();
     }
     return out;
 }`